# How to out put charset=iso-8859-1 in an excel reader for php?

Tags: php, excel, iso-8859-1

the code have this one

```
$retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? $retstr : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

, but i want to change it on charset=iso-8859-1 ...
caracters like ë , ' " , out put are wrong symbols .

Please any idea?

Comment: What excel reader library are you using; and what do you want to do with the content (chances are, if you want to convert it from the encoding used in the file itself to iso-8859-1, you'll need to use the iconv() or mb_convert_encoding() functions)

Comment: Yes this is what i need to do , please how can i use the iconv code to out put iso-8859-1 ?

i am using this https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [iconv()](http://www.php.net/function.iconv)? For each cell containing string data, use iconv to convert from the file encoding to iso-8859-1

Comment: is this the right one ?

$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "auto", "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: No, "auto" isn't an encoding, and this argument should be the encoding you want to convert __to__ (ie "ISO-8859-1").... and your third argument should be the encoding you're converting __from__ (ie, the encoding used in the file itself)

Comment: i dont know what encoding is , how can i find it ? is not shown here $retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? $retstr : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr); ?? please can u make an example for me ?

Answer (score 1):

The first few lines of the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation) say how to do this using the php-excel-reader library itself when you actually read the file:

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls", true, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Otherwise, it defaults to UTF-8, and you can convert strings individually from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 using:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: nÃ« â€˜FBâ€™ pÃ«r â€˜NatÃ«n e BardhÃ« â€™

is doing it again :((((